# Verifying the formula for the perimeter of an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, elliptic-integrals, arc-length

I've been working on the formula for the perimeter of an ellipse, but wasn't able to validate the expression I got while researching online. I'm looking for someone on this forum to perhaps help me with that

The expression I got for the perimeter of an ellipse with semi-major axis a and semi-minor axis b is

> $$4\frac{aπ}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2\frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}\right)^{2n}}{1-2n}$$

Is this accurate?

Comment: This looks (more or less !) to be Bessel's formula. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference

Comment: I've checked this numerically and it agrees with the complete elliptic function solution. The question is, how did you arrive at this equation?

Comment: @ Cye Waldman, where could I show you my derivation?